# How to send ember js header request without ember data

Tags: wordpress, cookies, ember.js, http-headers, wp-api

I'm trying to make a call to the [wp-api.org](http://wp-api.org) plugin for Wordpress. I want to show all users, and I want to use cookie authentication. Therefore I need to send a header request as explained on the website like this:

```
options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce);

    if (beforeSend) {
        return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

The following code I am using in my model:

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     return Ember.$.ajax({
          url: "http://myurl.com/wp-json/users/",
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          data: JSON.stringify({}),
          beforeSend:  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce);
        });


  }
});
```

At the moment the site returns this message because the authentication failed, but I am logged in and cookies are set:

```
[{"code":"json_user_cannot_list","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to list users."}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
   return Ember.$.ajax({
      url: "http://myurl.com/wp-json/users/",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify({}),
      beforeSend:  function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: this work, but the WP_API_settings is not defined so stil get an error and didn't know how get it work. This has something to do with `wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'WP_API_Settings', array( 'root' => esc_url_raw( get_json_url() ), 'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_json' ) ) );
` but don't know how to implement that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with WP so cannot help here

Answer (score 0):

the beforeSend property needs to be a function that is passed `xhr`, like in your first example, in your second code snippet `xhr` will be undefined.